# cech cohomology in topos

Tags: cohomology, grothendieck-topology, descent, cech-cohomology

Hi,

The following result seems to be well known, but I can't come up with a proof.

Suppose that $C$ is a topos and that $F\to G$ is an effective epimorphism in $C$. If $P$ is
any abelian sheaf on $C$, then the
object $RHom(G,P)$ is computed by the bicomplex
$$
RHom(F,P)\to RHom(F\times_G F,P)\to RHom(F\times_G F\times_G F, P)\to \dots
$$

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: See SGA4.V.7, especially Theorem 7.4.1.